# Heroku Internal Server Error on Django Application with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' in logs

Tags: django, heroku

I am currently trying to deploy a django project via Heroku, but the app is displaying an Internal Server Error.

Checked the logs by running `heroku logs -tail <app-name>` which I am assuming that the following error is causing the errror:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`

I've tried a different stackoverflow solution, but did not have any luck with it. Here are the following steps:

1. `pipenv install matplotlib`
2. Added the following in my models.py (even tried in settings.py)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Heroku Logs**

```
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361025+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/config/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361025+00:00 app[web.1]: path('', include('users.urls')),
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361025+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361025+00:00 app[web.1]: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361026+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361028+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361028+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361028+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361029+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361029+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361029+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361029+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361030+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/users/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361030+00:00 app[web.1]: from . import views
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361030+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/users/views.py", line 9, in <module>
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361030+00:00 app[web.1]: from .utils import searchProfiles, paginateProfiles
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361031+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/users/utils.py", line 1, in <module>
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361031+00:00 app[web.1]: from turtle import left
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361031+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361031+00:00 app[web.1]: import tkinter as TK
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361032+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361032+00:00 app[web.1]: import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
2022-04-06T01:50:43.361032+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.5.0
autopep8==1.6.0
boto3==1.21.34
botocore==1.24.34
cycler==0.11.0
Django==4.0.3
django-cors-headers==3.11.0
django-environ==0.8.1
django-storages==1.12.3
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.1.0
fonttools==4.31.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
jmespath==1.0.0
kiwisolver==1.4.2
matplotlib==3.5.1
numpy==1.22.3
packaging==21.3
Pillow==9.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
pycodestyle==2.8.0
PyJWT==2.3.0
pyparsing==3.0.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
s3transfer==0.5.2
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==1.26.9
whitenoise==6.0.0
```

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.10.2
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn config.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: It sort of depends what your code is trying to do. If your app relies on rendering content to a graphical interface, then you can't host it on Heroku. If it doesn't, then you need to remove those dependencies from your project.

Comment: @solarissmoke the error started even before having `matplotlib` installed. I added that package due to other slackoverflow posts with the similar issues and people suggesting to install the package.

All the app is grabbing are images from AWS S3 to display into the frontend. Shouldn't even need _tkinter

Comment: Your code is trying to use `turtle` (`from turtle import left` in `users/utils.py`), which relies on tkinter. I think you need to figure out what that code is trying to do and try to drop the turtle dependency. Adding `matplotlib` is not going to solve it.